# Android SDK Config on Linux Prior to Eclipse/ADT Install?

Tags: java, android, linux, sdk, adt

I read [Lars Vogel's Android Development tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html) and then headed directly to the [Android SDK download page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

I already have the Eclipse Java EE IDE (Juno; 4.2) installed, and would like to only install the Android SDK and then the ADT Eclipse plugin so I can start working from my existing Eclipse instance. As such, I downloaded the 64-bit linux (I'm on Ubuntu) "SDK Only" .tgz and extracted it to the my `~/sandbox/android-sdk` directory.

Before I go and install the ADT Plugin, are there any "setup"/config steps with the SDK that I need to do ahead of time? If so, what? I'm even interested in optional tuning here. I only ask because the article referenced above is targeted at Windows users, and so are most of the other tutorials I've found. I'm worried that there might be some out-of-the-box functionality that the Windows SDK provides that must be dealt with manually for us Linux denizens. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, I believe the answer is no, there is nothing else you need to do before installing the ADT Plugin. If you wanted, you could open the SDK manager from `~/sandbox/android-sdk/tools/android` and install some of the SDKs, but there's no reason you can't just do that from Eclipse after you install ADT.

Comment: Thanks @drewhannnay (+1) - just a quick followup: are you sure you didn't make a typo when you said "*...and install some of the SDKs*"? Do you mean *plugins* or something similar? The Android SDK allows you to install...other SDKs?!? Thanks again!

Comment: The basic SDK download includes all the tools for working with Android, but does not actually include the SDK files any of the OS versions (Jelly Bean, Ice Cream Sandwich, etc). Before you can start developing, you will need to open the SDK manager as I described and download at least one of those OS SDKs. So yes, I suppose the Android SDK does allow you to install other SDKs. :)